# How to find all left cosets about a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

I have a group:

```
group = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4}}], Cycles[{{6, 7}}]}];
```

And I have s subgroup

```
subgroup = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{6,7}}],Cycles[{{2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,7}}]}];
```

We can check it:

```
ResourceFunction["SubgroupQ"][subgroup, group]
```

> True

So how to find all left cosets(or just the representative element in all left cosets) about `subgroup` in `group`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since two left cosets $g\cdot H$ and $h \cdot H$ satisfies $g\cdot H= h \cdot H$ is equavalent to $ h^{-1}\cdot g\in H$,we set it as the equivalence relationships and use `Gather`.

```
Gather[GroupElements[group],
   GroupElementQ[subgroup, PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[#1], #2]] &]
```

There are 4 cosets.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## First edit

Since $b\in aH$, if and only if $aH=bH$:

```
Union[Sort[#, Less] &/@ Table[Table[
    PermutationProduct[e, i], {i, GroupElements[subgroup]}], {e, 
    GroupElements[group]}]]
```

[image]

The representative elements are respectively:

```
First /@ %
```

> {Cycles[{}],Cycles[{{1,3}}],Cycles[{{3,6}}],Cycles[{{3,7}}]}

Ugly, but work.

## Second edit (The efficiency version)

```
leftcosets[{}, r_] := r
leftcosets[remaineles_, r_ : {}] := 
 Module[{representative = First[remaineles], coset}, 
  leftcosets[Complement[remaineles, 
    coset = Table[PermutationProduct[representative, i], {i, 
       GroupElements[subgroup]}]], Append[r, coset]]]
```

It very quick. I'll use a larger group as an example:

```
group = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2, 7, 10, 5, 8}, {3, 4}, {6, 
       9}}], Cycles[{{1, 6}, {2, 4, 8, 7, 10, 9}, {3, 5}}]}];
subgroup = GroupStabilizer[group, {3}];
```

#### Performance comparsion

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 result1 = Gather[GroupElements[group], 
    GroupElementQ[subgroup, 
      PermutationProduct[InversePermutation[#], #2]] &];]
```

> {17.0175, Null} ← cvgmt's method

```
AbsoluteTiming[result2 = leftcosets[GroupElements[group]];]
```

> {0.133693, Null} ← my method

Equal to inspection

```
SortBy[Sort /@ result1, First] === SortBy[Sort /@ result2, First]
```

> True

---

## Third edit (just get the representative element of left cosets)

```
Union[InversePermutation[RightCosetRepresentative[subgroup,#]]&/@GroupElements[group]]
```

> {Cycles[{}],Cycles[{{1,3}}],Cycles[{{3,6}}],Cycles[{{3,6,7}}]}

Answer (score 0):

Share another elegant method to **list all right cosets**. The only regret is that it cannot be used to find left cosets. Because The inverse of the right coset canonical representative about $p$ is not in the same left coset with $p$:

```
GatherBy[GroupElements[group], RightCosetRepresentative[subgroup, #] &]
```